# Creating a large amount of sprites and animations

Tags: animation, sprites

For my AP U.S. Government and Politics class, I am making a spinoff of Mortal Kombat. Because of time constraints, I'm using an open source version of the game and want to create new characters.  I have about two weeks to do the project and can invest about 1-4 hours most days. I want it to look as nice as it can with the limited knowledge, skill, and time that I have. What programs or techniques would be best for a beginner with my time constraint?

Comment: "The fastest" would be a simple stick figure with a photo for a head, but the question is if this is the aesthetics you are looking for. There are far too many options here to write an answer on a Q&A site. Which option to pick depends on what aesthetics exactly you are looking for and how much work you are willing to invest.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from and that my question is quite vague. I have about two weeks to do the project and can invest about 1-4 hours most days. I want it to look as nice as it can with the limited knowledge and skill that I have.

Comment: good, fast and many assets: choose any two. You can have many good assets, but that takes time.  You can create many assets quickly, but they will be crap. You can create one great asset to define your look, but you won't have time for more. You are on a time constraint, so you have to decide where to compromise between quality and quantity. This is a choice we can't make for you.

Comment: I appreciate your input and completely agree with you, Philipp. However I was looking for specific programs or techniques I could use to allow me to do this faster. I was just looking for pointers on where to start but my question may not have directly reflected my thoughts. I appreciate your time regardless.